# Unable to create database in sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have been trying to create a database in sqlite3 on the disk (C: drive) following the example on the sqlite-python tutorial site, but keep getting the error "unable to open database file". If i create the file in my project folder (I'm using Pycharm), the database file is created. I don't understand why i couldn't create it on the disk. my code is as follow:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None


def main():
    database_src="C:\sqlite\db\store.db"
    create_connection(database_src)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: i would like to see your code

Comment: i have just addaed the code

Comment: Is there any other message related to the error, like "permission error" or "file not found"?

Comment: Does the directory `C:\sqlite\db` already exist? If not, you’ll need to create it before trying to open/create a database inside it.

Comment: probably you are giving the wrong path to store.db

Comment: I didn't create the directory before trying to create a database in it. I have just created it, and now it works. Plus i have to use double backslashess "\\". Thanks jbg and khizard.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows-style pathing, you need to escape your `\` characters properly.

```
database_src="C:\\sqlite\\db\\store.db"
```

The `\\` character is different than `\s`.